# Does Slack consume more local storage when I have lots of muted channels?

Tags: slack

In order to avoid joining and leaving channels that I only *need* for a short time, but regularly, I have many Slack channels filed away into groups.

Does this make Slack *pre-load* content in all those channels in the background, thus eating up bandwidth & storage space?

I'd like to adjust my Slack habits to reduce bandwidth & storage space, if it pre-downloads even muted, unopened, etc. channels.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that backs up these assumptions? Like, is your drive filling up and can you see that space being used up in Slack folders?

Comment: Slack _has to_ download channel content at some point. It's not an "assumption". The question only pertains to the rules by which it does so.

For what it's worth, `du -sh ~/Library/Application\ Support/Slack/Cache` shows a certain size which I'd like to reduce. After leaving channels, it has so far not shrunk much, though.